# MS Access (w/ linked SQL tables) form where rows are transformed to columns for data entry

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2013

I have a MS Access w/ linked SQL tables. There is a table for recording the different projects and the people working on them. The table is of this form

| ProjectID | PersonID | PersonTitle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 123 | VP |
| 12 | 124 | Senior |
| 12 | 125 | Junior |
| 13 | 123 | VP |
| 13 | 124 | Senior |
| 13 | 126 | Junior |
| 13 | 127 | Junior |
| 14 | 456 | VP |
| 14 | 457 | Senior |
| 14 | 458 | Senior |
| 14 | 459 | Junior |
| 14 | 460 | Junior |

I am trying to see if it is possible to create a MS Access Form to enter the above information, but the form should appear in the following format,

| ProjectID | VP1 | VP2 | Senior1 | Senior2 | Junior1 | Junior2 | Junior3 | Junior4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 123 |  | 124 |  | 125 |  |  |  |
| 13 | 123 |  | 124 |  | 126 | 127 |  |  |
| 14 | 456 |  | 457 | 458 | 459 | 460 |  |  |

So when a new project is added the PersonTitle columns will be blank and the user should be able enter information here. Is this possible?

I tried the crosstab feature but this did not allow for data entry.

For simplification, you can assume there will be at max 2 VPs, 2 Seniors and 4 Juniors for each Project. But if there is a way to dynamically update the Forms to allow for any number of roles that would be great (but not counting on it). Any of the title columns can remain blank

I am trying to see if there is a way to achieve this without creating new columns called VP1, VP2 etc as that would be difficult to manage

Comment: Review https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/bound-denormalized-form.251740/

Answer (score 0):

Without extensive VBA and SQL code, you may not be able to achieve that form to populate that table since both carry different rowwise granularity. Proposed wide-format form carries project level only and long-format table carries project and person levels. Instead, why not build a form in same long format aligned to original table structure?

Given you state the maximum possible person per project rules, consider pre-populating for every new project those maximum possible titles. Below query can be run with an MS Access [data macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200) for every `INSERT` into `projects` table.  Alternatively, you can use a trigger in SQL Server.

- Using the `NOT EXISTS` subquery, query avoids appending duplicates into table.
- The maximum possible persons on each project can be stored in a `project_persons_lookup` table.
- Notice the use of cross join (comma separated tables in `FROM` clause) for ever pairwise match between project and possible persons.

```sql
INSERT INTO project_persons (Project ID, PersonTitle)
SELECT p.ProjectID, ppl.PersonTitle
FROM projects p, possible_persons_lookup ppl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM project_persons sub
  WHERE sub.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
    AND sub.PersonTitle = ppl.PersonTitle
)
```

Then create a form of `project_persons` that will only allow user to update (not add or delete) persons in long format via a datasheet/continuous subform on main project form:

| ProjectID | PersonTitle | PersonID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | VP | ...combo box to persons table... |
|  | VP | " |
|  | Senior | " |
|  | Senior | " |
|  | Junior | " |
|  | Junior | " |
|  | Junior | " |
|  | Junior | " |
|  |  |  |
| 1002 | VP | ...combo box to persons table... |
|  | VP | " |
|  | Senior | " |
|  | Senior | " |
|  | Junior | " |
|  | Junior | " |
|  | Junior | " |
|  | Junior | " |
|  |  |  |